My weight paint brush only adds. Help?
Hey so I am trying to paint this model and I can add weight easily, but when I click subtract or try to use ctrl and click it doesn’t work either. It works randomly. I am using 4.2. On my old pc i didn’t have this problem. The black empty weights are new as well. I’m used to seeing the blue. Thanks anyone 


Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

Please don't take photos of your monitor. Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interference like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns on the surface of the monitor. Use Blender's built-in Screenshot generator from its Window > Save Screenshot menu.
